# Is “unlikely liar” a correct way to descibe a person?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Is *unlikely liar* a correct way to describe a person who is unlikely to lie?

Comment: An *liar* is somebody who lies or has lied, and adding *unlikely* doesn't change that. I would say that an *unlikely liar* is somebody you thought was unlikely to lie, but who actually did.

Comment: it is nonsensical to mix probability with an adjective (that has already tagged someone's condition)

Comment: @user2325442 Firstly, 'liar' is a noun. Secondly, 'a possible / probable liar' are totally acceptable; non-intersective ('a fake diamond'; 'a former president')) and possibly non-intersective adjectives are well known.

Comment: Then there’s Daniel Silva’s [*The Unlikely Spy*](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Unlikely_Spy.html?id=WRwlDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button) where, as @PeterShor notes above, the protagonist is a professor who becomes a spy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary definitions and example sentences should be given, but there will then be uncertainty as to which sense of 'unlikely' is the default one here.

Used of a person, I'd say the default sense here is as given among the senses at [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/unlikely):

> **unlikely** ... ... 2 not typical ... unusual in an interesting way; unusual, special, unique...
>
> *He’s a very unlikely romantic hero.*

[reformatted]

So the required 'not really likely to be true' sense is at best in doubt here (though context almost always helps to disambiguate different possible polysemes). The sense is rather 'unexpected; not a natural'.

'It is unlikely that he's a liar' gives the required sense.

Answer (score 2):

No. *Unlikely* as an attributive adjective actually accepts that its associated noun is **true.** Dictionaries don't really help with nuances like this:

> [**unlikely**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unlikely)
>
> Not likely to happen, be done, or be true; improbable.
>
> *‘an unlikely explanation’
>
>   ‘it is unlikely that they will ever be used’
>
>   [with infinitive] ‘prices are unlikely to change’*
>
> — Oxford via Lexico

An unlikely explanation is an explanation, albeit unexpected and improbable.

An unlikely teacher is someone who teaches, although you didn't really expect them to do that.

An unlikely liar **is a liar,** however surprising it is that they are.